# Rails 4.2 rendering an Array in js.erb results in a crash

Tags: javascript, rails-activerecord, render, ruby-on-rails-4.2, activerecord-relation

So, I'm trying to render an Array of objects in my js.erb file. My controller method that's make the array looks like below:

```ruby
def process_report
  start_date = Date.parse(params[:start_date])
  finish_date = Date.parse(params[:finish_date])
  done = params[:done].to_i
  kind = params[:kind].to_i
  late = to_boolean params[:late]
  @invoices = Invoice.where(due_date: start_date..finish_date,
                            done: done,
                            kind: kind,
                            late: late)
  if params[:approved] != ""
    @invoices = @invoices.reject{ |i| i.status.description != params[:approved] }
  end
  render 'complete_report.js.erb',
         collection: @invoices, format: :js, status: :ok
end
```

I know it's a little bit ugly this code. I'm intend to refactoring it. So, if the view passes the `params[:approved]`, I reject some objects from the collection. If the view didn't pass this param, the `reject` method isn't called and `@invoices` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. As you guys can see at the end of this method, I render an `js.erb` file. Inside this file, I have this code:

```js
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
  var tableLine = $("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'invoice', locals: {invoice: invoice}, formats: :html) %>");
  $("#report_invoice_table").append(tableLine);
<% end %>
```

The javascript code executes normally when `@invoices` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. The problems comes up if `params[:approved]` isn't empty. The `reject` method filter the objects that I don't want, but returns `@invoices` as an `Array`. When it's an `Array`, the javascript code simply don't execute. I don't even get an error.

**So, concluding:** why when I passes an `ActiveRecord::Relation` to the js.erb so it can be rendered, my javascript code works normally and did not when I passes an `Array`?

I searched a lot and didn't got close of finding the answer. Sorry for the bad english. Feel free to correct me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out the problem. In js.erb file, I got the a code that calculates the sum of all invoices after trying to rendering the invoices.

```javascript
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
  <% puts invoice.inspect %>
  var tableLine = $("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'invoice', 
    locals: {invoice: invoice}, formats: :html) %>");
  $("#report_invoice_table").append(tableLine);
<% end %>

<% if @invoices.empty? %>
  $("#report_total_value").css("display", "none");
<% else %>
  $("#report_total_value").css("display", "inline-block");
  $("#report_total_value").text("Total: R$ " + <%= @invoices.sum(:value) %>);
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I use the `.sum` method. All the problem was caused because `.sum` is a method only available to `ActiveRecord::Relation`. For the `Array` class, it must use another method.

```javascript
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
  <% puts invoice.inspect %>
  var tableLine = $("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'invoice',
    locals: {invoice: invoice}, formats: :html) %>");
  $("#report_invoice_table").append(tableLine);
<% end %>

<% if @invoices.empty? %>
  $("#report_total_value").css("display", "none");
<% else %>
  $("#report_total_value").css("display", "inline-block");
  $("#report_total_value").text("Total: R$ "
  + <%= @invoices.map{ |i| i.value }.reduce(0, :+) %>);
<% end %>
```

After changed it, my code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to render it as a collection:

```
var tableLine = $("<%= j render(partial: 'invoice', collection: @invoices, formats: :html) %>");
$("#report_invoice_table").append(tableLine);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but didn't work. `ActiveRecord::Relation` and `Array` aren't working when I trying rendering as a collection. And I still getting no error message.